# mysql WHERE SET datatype contains item

Tags: mysql

I have a table that uses a SET datatype for one of the fields, and to check if the field contains a specific element I use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myset LIKE %value%;
```

This works most of the time, but two of the potential values have the same word, i.e. one possible element in the set is Poodle and another is Toy Poodle. If I do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myset LIKE %Poodle%;
```

It returns all rows that have either Poodle or Toy Poodle. I want it to only return if the field contains Poodle. If I remove the wildcards then it will only return the rows that have ONLY Poodle. So basically, if the table was:

```
id | myset
-------------------------
1  | "Poodle"
2  | "Toy Poodle"
3  | "Poodle","Toy Poodle"
4  | "Toy Poodle","Poodle"
```

I need a select statement that would return 1,3, and 4 but not 2. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) method?

Answer (score 16):

You need to do: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Poodle',myset)>0` as described in [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html)

Comment: Not sure how I overlooked that...feeling a bit foolish now. That was where I got the information to use LIKE %...%, just somehow missed the FIND_IN_SET part

Comment: now i know. glad to add another set of knowledge in my brains database

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '"Poddle"', myset ) > 0
```

looking for `"` would be important to eliminate record #2

Answer (score 1):

sorry if I'm completely missing the point here, but are the quotations in your resultset actually stored in the db?

what I mean is, does the actual value of the first row equal...

```
"Poodle"
```

...or have you just quoted these values for presentation purposes, in which case the first value would actually be...

```
Poodle
```

Only reason I ask is, why not just do a query like...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE myset LIKE '%"Poodle"%';
```

Apologies if I've massively missed the point or over-simplified beyond the point of recognition.

good luck with a fix anyway!

Comment: no, the quotes are not stored in the DB I was just using them for presentation in the question to signify that each was a separate possible value

Comment: so would the actual string for id 2 be Poodle,Toy Poodle